# leetcode inorder binary search tree traversal

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, inorder

I'm working on a leetcode problem: Given the root of a binary tree, return the inorder traversal of its nodes' values. I was thinking I can push the right, root and left value on a stack and then pop them to put them to a vector to revert the order. However, I am getting this error:() line 22 is the `vector.push_back(root->right->val)`. I'm not sure why I am getting that

> Line 22: Char 43: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'TreeNode' (solution.cpp)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:31:43

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> inorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
        std::stack<TreeNode*> stack;
        std::vector<int> vector;
        
        stack.push(root->left);
        while(!stack.empty()){
            root->right = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
            vector.push_back(root->right->val);
            
            if(root){
                stack.push(root);
            }
        
            if(root->left){
                stack.push(root->left);
            }
        }
        
        return vector;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you used debugger to check if  `right` is null?

Comment: What if `root` is nullptr or `root->left` in the first `push`? Either do a null check before pushing to stack or everytime you are dereferencing. Secondly, the names of `vector` and `stack` could be something other than the datatypes itself